# iterating over the collection on a certain condition in a data structure

Tags: java, guava

I have created the data structure as shown below that is google based guava table and it is  shown below

```
final Table<String, String, List<String>> values = HashBasedTable.create();
        values.put("bon", "currency", Lists.newArrayList("ccdd","rode1","cwey","Certy"));
```

below is the way in which i am iterating over this collection

```
Map <String , List<String>>fmap = new  HashMap < String , List<String>>();      
for (Cell<String, String, List<String>> cell1: values.cellSet()){
    if (cell1.getRowKey() != null && cell1.getRowKey().equalsIgnoreCase("bon") )
                {
                fmap.put(cell1.getColumnKey(), cell1.getValue());
            }
        }
```

now i want to modify my condition in such a way that if row key contains the value of bon
and the column key contains these values "ccdd","rode1","cwey","Certy" then it should fill the map
named fmap such that on iteration map would look like this

```
Key        Value 
ccdd        currency
rode1       currency
cwey        currency    
Certy       currency
```

please advise how to achieve this
as the solution advise is still not working please

Comment: if (cell1.getRowKey() != null && cell1.getRowKey().equalsIgnoreCase("bon") cell1.getColumnKey().contains("ccdd","rode1","cwey","Certy") )

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating through all the values in the Guava Table. Try to get the row with row key `bon` and then loop through the valid column keys to populate your map.

```
Map <String , List<String>>fmap = new  HashMap < String , List<String>>();   
List<String> validColumnKeys = Arrays.asList("ccdd","rode1","cwey","Certy"); 
Map<String, List<String>> row = values.row("bon");
for(String columnKey:validColumnKeys) {
    fmap.put(columnKey, row.get(columnKey));
}
```

Comment: no value is still displayed as null in this case but key is populated , Please advise how to populate the value